# How to run a terminal command in Django app?

Tags: python, django, terminal, background-task

I want to execute a terminal command whenever I visit the index page in my Django app. I've done it outside of the Django app and it worked. Outside of my Django app I ran:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('python hello.py')
```

The **hello.py** file which contains a regular print statement **print('Hello')** and in the terminal from where I ran the command using the above script, it of course prints "**Hello**" like a charm.

My question is, is it possible to run something like below in my Django app?

```
def index(request):
    subprocess.run('python manage.py process_tasks')

    today = datetime.now()
    schedule_time = datetime(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day, hour=today.hour + 5,
                         minute=today.minute + 1,
                         tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

    run_until = datetime(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day, hour=today.hour + 5,
                     minute=today.minute + 1,
                     tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

    print_hello(schedule=schedule_time, repeat=20, repeat_until=run_until)

    return HttpResponse(f'Background task running...')
```

By including this command **subprocess.run('python manage.py process_tasks')** in the view function it will at least eliminate me opening another terminal to run **python manage.py process_tasks** to get the app to work in the background for me.

The app went to the page successfully but the background tasks aren't picking up and in the terminal it is saying **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'background_task'**. Here's the image with the error message for a better understanding. Thanks!

[ModuleNotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qrV1.png)

Comment: Please paste error messages as text. Note that `subprocess.run` is blocking; if you want it to be nonblocking, use `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Hey mate, I'm getting the same error even with subprocess.Popen. If I should paste the error message as text in the comment I won't be allowed to it seems. I've attached an image to the question.

Comment: is your app running in a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, i figured this was the problem after narrowing down the error. It was using the python from the PATH and not the venv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... After narrowing down the error. It was trying to use the python.exe in the PATH and not the virtual environment.

```
subprocess.Popen('C:...project_name\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe manage.py process_tasks')
```

That executed the task perfectly!